# How to echo latest mysql row and some previous column?

Tags: php, mysql, echo

I am new in php. I have a problem. I want to fetch data from Mysql db and print it on my PHP page. I want to print latest record and some previous data of selected column. For example i have a two tables

```
table1( id, student_name )
table2: ( id, student_id, English, Math, Physics......., Total Marks, Obtain Marks and grade)
```

**PROBLEM:** I want that i can fetch whole new record but i want that i can also fetch previous grade of the student.

**Can it is possible? How i Can do it?**

Comment: Make use of the mysql SELECT statement. You may need to look at some tutorials on the internet.

Comment: 1. See normalisation

Comment: Not sure what you need here.

Comment: @Mike if I use SELECT statement then how to fetch previous record of a colum? Coz when i echo the record it print latest data

Comment: @Akshay I want to print previous data with new data. For example as i say i want to print whole row which contain new record but the data in grade column i want to display it with new data and also old data like if new grade of student is A+ and Previous grade is A i want to print it both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE (student_id=2) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2
    ) sub
    ORDER BY id ASC
```

You should be able to select the two last rows.

Edit syntax formatting:

```
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo $rows[0]["grade"]; // new grade
    echo $rows[1]["grade"]; // previous grade
```

Comment: I dont want to echo whole row i want to echo selected column

Comment: Ehh, when you have the data you can easily display the data for the selected column.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

If you try:

        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        echo $rows[0]["grade"]; // new grade
        echo $rows[1]["grade"]; // previous grade

Syntax could be a bit off. I'm doing C# these days... :-P

Comment: Stefan when i call the colum Name it also print two records but i want only print two records of column Grade

Comment: Thanks Stefan i will try it :0

Comment: Could you please update your post with your code? :)

Comment: Stefan my code is bit different from my given example in question. In my query i join multiple tables.

Comment: I use your answer but it show me an error `Undefined offset: 0 `

Comment: Hey Sunny, you might want to give this a try $rows["grade"][0];

Comment: Instead of mysql_fetch_assoc you need to fetch all results btw: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php. Else there will only be one row. Sorry about that.

Comment: Now it show `Undefined offset: 1`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following:

```
$query = SELECT t1.*,t2.* FROM table1 as t1
LEFT JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.id = t2.student_id
where t1.id = '1' ORDER BY t2.student_id desc LIMIT 2

$result = mysql_query($query);
$fetch_record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$grade = $fetch_record[0]['pass-your-column-name'];
```

Comment: show error `Undefined offset: 0 `

Comment: you can remove the offset [0] and directly try with this `echo $fetch_record['pass-your-column-name'];`